# Compare 2 images directly

Tags: compositing-nodes, uv-image-editor

I would like to compare 2 images with little color changes to another. (To be specific, the raw render result and the output of my compositing viewer-node).

For now, i use two UV/Image Editor windows, displaying my two images. The problem now is that i need to resize/move both images so that the edge is fitting correctly (wich is unpleasent work). Also, when moving the border around, both images also move a bit...

[image: Two images at a UV/Image_Editor-Border]

Is there a better method to display two images on top of each other with a movable border between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the compositor you can use the split viewer node.

[image]

From the [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/output/split_viewer.html?highlight=split%20viewer):

> The SplitViewer node takes two images and displays one-half of each on each side (top socket on the right half, bottom socket input on the left). Use this node for making side-by-side comparisons of two renderings/images, perhaps from different render layers or from different scenes. When transitioning between scenes, you want to be sure the stop action is seamless; use this node to compare the end of one scene with the beginning of another to ensure they align.

[image]

Comment: That works, but it has to re-composite the whole image each time i change the factor. Is there any other way that first renders both images and then performs this effect?

Comment: You could output both images to disk and then set up a new compositing file with just the 2 image inputs and the Split Viewer node.

Answer (score 3):

The Render Result of the UV/Image Editor has 8 slots for render output. I VERY often used this to compare changes between different renders.

To use different slots, open the Render Result <kbd>F11</kbd> and press the number of the slot you want (1 thru 8). Then render. The result will show up in that slot. Now, press the number of another slot (1 thru 8) and render again. Now, you can swap very quickly between the two (or more) results without having to re-render. You won't have a movable border, but you will be able to compare your renders to each other.